# Independent Clauses? Noun phrases placed former to placing subject?

Tags: phrases, syntax, noun-phrases

“I fell in love with her courage, her sincerity, and her flaming self respect. **And it's these things I'd believe in, even if the whole world indulged in wild suspicions that she wasn't all she should be**. I love her and it is the beginning of everything.” 
― F. Scott Fitzgerald

I think I may discern a complete sentence in aiming to observe a verb and verb arguments. In *And it's these things I'd believe in*, may it seem that a noun phrase *these things* (argument of *believe*[?]) seems all right to go former to placing a subject, *I*? I guess I may frequently think it goes subject verb object (noun phrase), not maybe (noun phrase) *these things*, subject, *I*. Do you say *And it's these things I'd believe in*, independent clause, *even if the whole world indulged in wild suspicions that she wasn't all she should be.*, conditional clause?

Answer (score 3):

You're mostly right; but the the main clause needs a little explaining. It  employs a construction called a *cleft* as an "information packaging" device, rearranging the constituents of the underlying simple clause to emphasize *these things*

The  "original" clause here is this:

> And I believe in these things ...

To emphasize *these things*  we start with a new copular main clause having the "dummy" (semantically empty) pronoun *it* as its subject and *these things* as its predicate complement. This position, immediately after the verb, is ordinarily the strongest position in a sentence, the typical location for new, more interesting information.

> It is **these things**

We now bring in the rest of the original as a relative clause referring to the emphasized constituent:

> It is these things [which] I believe in ...

Note that if the relativizer (*which* in this case) does not stand for the subject of the relative clause it may be omitted.

Otherwise your analysis is spot on.

Comment: I may read upon cleft. So in *And it's these things I'd believe in* *I (would[?]) (I’d) believe in*, I may get *I would believe in*. What is a grammatical function of would? Or may it go like *would believe* verb. So *And* conjunction, *it* (*it’s*) (not a subject[?]), (semantically empty[?]), *is* (a second copular verb to utilize cleft[?]) and so *And it’s these things* (cleft[?]). So I guess I may not get so a noun phrase, object, may go former to placing a subject, *I* in cleft utilization, or, I may not get may it seem like two clauses.

Comment: I may not get relativizer. So may this seem mostly one clause? I think you did text it seems to contain maybe two main clauses? There seems one object, *these things*, so maybe one clause? May you write something like this? *It is running I like.* I thank you, StoneyB.

Comment: @saySay *Relativizer* is the fashionable new jargon for what I grew up calling a *relative pronoun* (who, whom, which, that, &c). *These things* is the predicate complement of the main clause and the referent of the deleted relativizer which stands for the object of the preposition *in* in the relative clause. *I like running* → *It is running I like*.

Comment: Relative pronoun, I may get that. *these things* predicate complement of *believe* verb, or maybe *would believe* verb or maybe *is*. (I may not get if believe seems intransitive [I believe.]). So *I would believe in these things* seems like *(And) It is these things I would believe in.* What seems a main clause here, what verb, *believe*, or *would believe*? So *And it is these things*, main clause? I would believe in relative clause?

Comment: I may think upon it like this? *And it is these things(.[?]) (main clause), (which) I would believe in (relative clause{?]).* I may not get relativizers, when you may utilize them, when you may not. I guess it may go two clauses, And it is these things. (main [independent?] clause[?]) and ([which] I would believe in) (relative clause[?]). *And it is these things* may seem like a different independent clause to me. It may not seem like one. And so I guess you may write *It is running I like* like (And) It is these things I would believe in.